# Fabric.js remnants of old canvas remain

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I want to display the content of a canvas as the background of another canvas and draw a bunch of rectangles on there. I need to dynamically change:

- the canvas from which to load the background image for my `finalcanvas`
- which rectangles to draw

It's easiest if I start this process from scratch. I have imitated starting from scratch with a simple button. However, after redrawing my canvas, previous information from fabric.js remains present after dragging an item of a canvas a bit. This means that the old canvas was not cleared properly. I tried playing around with `.clear()` and `.depose()`, but to no avail.

In case the description is vague, here an image:

[image]

And an small reproducible example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="finalcanvas"></canvas>
  <canvas id="backgroundcanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.3/fabric.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    function load_plane_onto_active_canvas() {
      var c = document.getElementById('backgroundcanvas');
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      var bg = c.toDataURL("image/png");

      var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('finalcanvas', {
        width: 333,
        height: 333
      });

      canvas.setBackgroundImage(bg, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

      canvas.on("mouse:over", function(e) {
        console.log(e.target)
      });

      // add 100 rectangles
      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
          rect = new fabric.Rect({
            width: 10,
            height: 10,
            left: j * 15,
            top: i * 15,
            fill: 'green',
          })
          canvas.add(rect);
        }
      }
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      // fill the background canvas with red
      (function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("backgroundcanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
      }())

      load_plane_onto_active_canvas()
    }
  </script>
  <button onclick="load_plane_onto_active_canvas()">click me</button>

</body>

</html>
```

I hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you're creating a *new* instance of `fabric.Canvas` in your `load_plane_onto_active_canvas()` function. So when you're clicking the button, the existing canvases stay intact, and you're actually calling `clear()` on your freshly created canvas. The DOM becomes messed up at this point, with several nested canvases inside of each other - you can take a peek at the DOM inspector to see that.

What you can do instead is create the canvas instance just once, then work with a reference to it later in your other functions.

```js
const finalCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("finalcanvas", {
  width: 333,
  height: 333
});
// finalCanvas now exists in the global (window) scope

function load_plane_onto_active_canvas() {
  var c = document.getElementById("backgroundcanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var bg = c.toDataURL("image/png");
  
  finalCanvas.clear();

  finalCanvas.setBackgroundImage(bg, finalCanvas.renderAll.bind(finalCanvas));

  finalCanvas.on("mouse:over", function (e) {
    // console.log(e.target);
  });

  // add 100 rectangles
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      rect = new fabric.Rect({
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        left: j * 15,
        top: i * 15,
        fill: "green"
      });
      finalCanvas.add(rect);
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function () {
  // fill the background canvas with red
  (function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("backgroundcanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
  })();

  load_plane_onto_active_canvas();
};
document.querySelector("#b1").onclick = () => load_plane_onto_active_canvas();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.3/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="finalcanvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="backgroundcanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
<button id="b1">start from scratch</button>
```